# Out of memory MySql

Tags: mysql

Mysql returning error " **Out of memory**"  When performing simple query-

```
SELECT * from users WHERE login LIKE "%son";
```

Table has about 500mil rows and 2 columns

Total server **RAM 64G**
From what i have read, it's mostly because of other apps using the ram, bu it's not the case here, 40G~ ram is **dedicated to mysql**

Here is my.ini configuration 
(I have tried messing around with it, but  i think i just made it worse ) -
Thank you.

```
[mysqld]

port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL2/MySQL Server 5.7\Data

character-set-server=utf8

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="DESKTOP-0E18H6E.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="DESKTOP-0E18H6E-slow.log"
long_query_time=10

log-error="DESKTOP-0E18H6E.err"

server-id=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=300
query_cache_size=1000000

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=429M

thread_cache_size=10

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=844M

key_buffer_size=8M

read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G

innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_thread_concurrency=8

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000


innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_open_files=300 

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0


back_log=80


flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=32M    

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=4161

query_cache_type=0

sort_buffer_size=256K  
table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K    

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000

plugin_load="mysqlx"

loose_mysqlx_port=33060
```

Comment: `myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G` looks like a really wildly oversized value.

Comment: A) Don't use MyISAM unless you absolutely have to. InnoDB is significantly easier to tune. B) The key to InnoDB tuning is largely `innodb_buffer_pool_size` which you can set to 50-75% of the server's available memory if this server is 100% dedicated to MySQL.

Comment: What are the two columns the table has?

Comment: @Uueerdo name and lastname, P.s database is InnoDb I believe

Comment: @TomasKatlauskas where does the `login` field the query is filtering on come from?

Comment: @Uueerdo login = name :)

Comment: Have you tried returning the first N records/can you find the limit # that causes the error? How long is it running before you get the error?

Comment: Maybe using `RIGHT(login, 3) = 'son'` (instead of the LIKE expression) could help? _Also, is `users` a table? (as opposed to a VIEW)_

Comment: We need to see your  SHOW INDEX FROM users; text results.  Please add to original question.  We will have information on all indexes and cardinality, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server has 64G (used for more than MySQL purposes) so to ask for

```
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
```

would possibly cause OOM.

You cannot enable more RAM if you do not have it.

Try 6G (about 10% of your available RAM) and monitor.

Add to your `my.cnf` or `my.ini`

```
max_heap_table_size=429M # should always be same as tmp_table_size
```